# .htaccess 301 Redirecting old dynamic pages to static page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I looked through some other questions but no solutions seem to work.  Here's a quick example of some 13k 301 redirects I must do.  Here is one of which:

```
www.mysite.com/beta/index.php/cataloga/category/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=3
to
www.mysite.com/applications/
```

So here's what I've tried:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=3
RewriteRule ^/beta/index.php/cataloga/category/index.php$ /applications/ [R=301,L]
```

---

```
RewriteRule /applications/ ^Itemid=3  [R=301,L]
```

---

```
RewriteRule ^Itemid=3 /applications/ [R=301,L]
```

---

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/id=55&Itemid=3/.*$ /applications/
```

---

```
Redirect 301 /beta/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=3 /applications/
```

**EDIT**
Here is another sample URL I need to go to `/compare/`:

```
/beta/index.php/index.php/products/mysite/index.php/cataloga/category/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=37&Itemid=16
```

To check if Redirects were even working, I tested this and it worked fine:

`Redirect 301 /beta/index.php/products/hyperpress /`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=3\b
RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php$ /applications/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=37&Itemid=16\b
RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php$ /compare/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

- Leading slash is not matched in htaccess
- `?` at the end of target URI will strip off query strings

Comment: Thanks, it kind of worked.  If the url had `id=37&Itemid=16` I'd want it to go to a different static page though...ie. `/compare/`

Comment: ok in that case you need different rules as shown in my recent update to answer

Comment: Thanks, works for some instances.  Please see my EDIT with long URLs.  Why doesn't it work when I just try ^index.php$

Comment: For that you can use `RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php$ /compare/?`

Comment: Thanks again, I also tried asteriks (*) for catch all before.